# My Cat Palm leaves areturning Yellow with Brown spots, and some leaves with brown edges

Tags: watering, roots, palm, tropical

Recently purchased Cat Palm (2 weeks). Leaves are turning yellow, with now brown spots. And some leaves have brown edges. I am confused if this is a underwatering or overwatering problem. It does look root bound to me, should I repot will that be a big shock? Please share your thoughts/advice. Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are any of the branches healthy? Or are they all browning off? Any new growth at all?